# How to draw a Contour using CONREC php

Tags: php, arrays, contour

I'm having trouble drawing a contour from a regular grid.

```
X   Y   Value
0   50  5
1   51  5
2   52  6
3   53  6
etc.....
```

The problem, I think is getting the data array correct to then pass to the function.

I am using the PHP Conrec Contouring Subroutine written by Paul Bourke

http://paulbourke.net/papers/conrec/

http://paulbourke.net/papers/conrec/conrec.php_

http://paulbourke.net/papers/conrec/test.php_

My test arrays are

```
  $x=array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10); //Longitude 
  $y=array(50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60); //Latitude
  $v=array(5,5,6,6,8,8,9,9,9,5,6); //Value
  $z =count($v); //Number of contours??
```

The function I need to call is:`CONREC_contour($d,$x,$y,$z);`

The documentation explains that I need to create $d see below

$d is a 2D jagged array, with X on the first dim and Y on the second.
I say jagged as PHP does not support a true native multidimensional array type in the same way as other languages do. Thus, (C, Fortran, etc...) d[i,j] === (PHP) $d[i][j]

I'm struggling to understand and create the $d array correctly.

Can anyone please help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can look into the example how to create the $d array. If it doesn't help you can try my php implementation of a contourplot @ codeplex.com (https://contourplot.codeplex.com/). It uses some idea from indiemaps AS3 isolines implementation.